# TableView and CollectionView position & size automatically gets change in Storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have searched alot but found nothing on this issue.... :(

I have added a **CollectionView** and two **TableView** in a storyboard.

Every thing was working perfectly fine.

Now the Problem is both TableViews and CollectionView is automatically gets change their position & size and moved in storyboard's left upper corner.

Almost hide themselves.

When i drag them one by one and change layout / position, they again change their position and size when i select any other object(Button/Label) on storyboard.

Here is the Screen shoot i just take of my storyboard.

I have removed / deleted the storyboard and congifure it again from start but the problem is same :(

what is this all happening.... I don't know what to do here?

[image]

Please help me on this issue.

**CollectionView is just behing that misplaced TableView in storyboard's left upper corner.**

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: i am using XCode 6.1

Comment: Haven't worked much with that version, but this issue maybe arising due to AutoLayout or the new view size properties introduced in Xcode 6 & above. Try disabling AutoLayout.

Comment: after disabling AutoLayOut, problem is solved... :)

Comment: @LibranCoder but i was working with Auto LayOut Enable since last week on this storyboard. it was working fine.

Comment: Maybe. Xcode behaves in strange ways at times. ;)

Comment: hmmm we can't say nothing more ... :(

Comment: @LibranCoder you may add this as answer, so that i will mark it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63795/discussion-between-libran-coder-and-zubair).

Comment: Done that. You may mark it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't worked much with XCode version 6, but this issue maybe arising due to AutoLayout or the new view size properties introduced in Xcode 6 & above. Try disabling AutoLayout.